# Childs go beyond of grid block

Tags: html, css

There is a .classes block with grid styles, but its .class children (which contain the slider block) are larger than necessary. That is, if you place three blocks in a row, they will go beyond the boundaries of the parent block.

css:

```
.classes {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 2em;
}

.class {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: var(--second);
    height: 13em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
}

.class-footer-block {
    height: 100%;
    padding: .5em 0 0 0;
}

.class-personal-estimates {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    gap: .5em;
    overflow: auto;
}

[class^="estimate"] {
    min-width: 1em;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: .2em;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <header data-include="header"></header>
    <main>
        <div class="classes">
            <div  data-include="class-plate">
                <div id="class" class="class">
                    <div class="class-header-block">
                        <h2>ДО К-28</h2>
                        <button class="class-action-btn">
                            <i class="three-dot-icon"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="class-middle-block">
                        <span class="class-description">
                            Анализ данных (лаб занятия) 1234567898765432
                        </span>
                        <span class="class-owner">
                            Alexander Slabospitsky
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="class-footer-block">
                        <div class="class-personal-estimates">
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate2"></div>
                            <div class="estimate3"></div>
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate3"></div>
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate2"></div>
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate2"></div>
                            <div class="estimate3"></div>
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate3"></div>
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate2"></div>
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate2"></div>
                            <div class="estimate3"></div>
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate3"></div>
                            <div class="estimate1"></div>
                            <div class="estimate2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div  data-include="class-plate"></div>
            <div  data-include="class-plate"></div>
            <div  data-include="class-plate"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
```

Other `<div  data-include="class-plate"></div>` contain the same as the first

if limit `.class-footer-block` (for example width: 20em;) everything will be fine, but not as I need. I need to reach the maximum width of this .class-footer-block, but so that it does not go beyond the boundaries

jsfiddle link for demonstrate problem https://jsfiddle.net/mplaksyuk/4w1qn5em/3/

Comment: Hi, the behaviour seems to be connected with the fact `.class-personal-estimates` is a flex container but its flex items don't wrap and have a fixed min-width. The only thing that comes to my mind is to try `repeat( auto-fit, minmax(450px, 1fr) )` on the grid container

Comment: same idea as Sigma, but also width instead of min-width for estimateX and flex-shrink : https://jsfiddle.net/ujcvdrqw/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sigma, G-Cyrillus, thank you so much! Еverything works as it should)